# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS - Audio issue - input devices not available & Bluetooth issue

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, input-devices, pavucontrol

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP Victus laptop , and i notice that i'm facing an issue with my input audio device which is not detected , when checking settings -> sounds -> input it's grayed off :(see the screen shot attached) :

[ubuntu sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOEym.png)

I tried to reinstall the whol system by using another ubuntu version 20 for example but the issue still persists .

When working an external mic it works fine , i uninstalled audio drivers and without any result :

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

I verified with pavicontrol i see that the input device is unplugged :(see the screen shot attached)
[Pavucontrol input configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX1Lo.png)

Additional informations that can be useful : `aplay -l` command output :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

> lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3

```
 01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:2291] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
06:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:1640]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
06:00.5 Multimedia controller [0480]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [1022:15e2] (rev 60)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_pci_acp6x
    Kernel modules: snd_pci_acp3x, snd_rn_pci_acp3x, snd_pci_acp5x, snd_pci_acp6x, snd_acp_pci, snd_rpl_pci_acp6x, snd_pci_ps, snd_sof_amd_renoir, snd_sof_amd_rembrandt
06:00.6 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:15e3]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller [103c:8a22]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
07:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:161f]
```

I have another issue i don't know if it's related to the first one or not , when connection headphones with Bluetooth , it appears that it's connected but the sound still come from the laptop directly , and in pacucontrol the headphones are mentionned as unplugged too .

Please could you help me with this issue .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS I had same issue
I used

`sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio`

`systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager`

and I found ubuntu update installation was pending I installed and restarted then it started working now.